# NodeJS botbuilder SDKv4

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots

How can I store the values of the user input? For example I've created this dialog and I want to create an email and in the same time store them in a DB, but I am not sure where to add the functions.

Thanks

Constructor:

```
constructor(conversationState) {

        this.dialogStateAccessor = conversationState.createProperty(DIALOG_STATE_ACCESSOR);
        this.holidayAccessor = conversationState.createProperty(HOLIDAY_ACCESSOR);
        this.conversationState = conversationState;

        this.dialogSet = new DialogSet(this.dialogStateAccessor);
        this.dialogSet.add(new ChoicePrompt(MONTH_PROMPT));
        this.dialogSet.add(new ChoicePrompt(START_DATE_PROMPT));
        this.dialogSet.add(new ChoicePrompt(END_DATE_PROMPT));

        this.dialogSet.add(new WaterfallDialog(HOLIDAY_DIALOG, [
            this.promptForMonth.bind(this),
            this.promptForstartDate.bind(this),
            this.promptForendDate.bind(this),
        ]));
    }
```

TurnContext:

```
case ActivityTypes.Message:
                const holiday = await this.holidayAccessor.get(turnContext, null);

                const dc = await this.dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);

                if (!dc.activeDialog) {
                    if (!holiday) {
                        await dc.beginDialog(HOLIDAY_DIALOG);
                    }
                    else {
                        await turnContext.sendActivity(
                            `An email was sent to your manager for approval`);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Just checking, did the answer I provided actually help you? Re-reading the question, I think I got my wires crossed on what you were asking.

Comment: Hi, yes. It was a bit different than what I’ve asked, but it helped me to understand more. I did some changes to my code and it works. Tried to upvote your answer but I do not have enough points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you need to create and pass the userState store in your index.js file first.

```js
const { ConversationState, MemoryStorage, UserState } = require('botbuilder');

[...]

const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);

[...]

const bot = new ExampleBot(conversationState, userState);
```

In your bot.js file, include and instantiate userState and assign a user profile:

```js
class ExampleBot {
    constructor(conversationState, userState) {
    [...]

    const USER_PROFILE = 'userProfile';
    this.userProfile = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE);
    this.userState = userState;

    [...]
}
```

Now you can access the userState. You can do so as part of the OnTurn:

```js
async onTurn(turnContext) {
    if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        const userProfile = await this.userProfile.get(turnContext, {});
        const conversationData = await this.conversationData.get(
            turnContext, { promptedForUserName: false });
        if (!userProfile.name) {
            if (conversationData.promptedForUserName) {
                userProfile.name = turnContext.activity.text;
                await turnContext.sendActivity(`Thanks ${userProfile.name}.`);
                conversationData.promptedForUserName = false;
            } else {
                await turnContext.sendActivity('What is your name?');
                conversationData.promptedForUserName = true;
            }
            await this.userProfile.set(turnContext, userProfile);
            await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Or as part of the waterfall / step:

```js
async someWaterfallStep(step) {
        const user = await this.userProfile.get(step.context, {});

        if (!user.name) {
            [do something]
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity(`Hello ${user.name}. Nice to meet you!`);
            return step.endDialog()
        }
    }
```

You can read more about setting user state in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript).

Hope of help!